# Screenshot based on JPanel location and size

Tags: java, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of what's behind of a JPanel but i get a black image after saving it.

Here's the code:

```
private void takeScreenshot(String print){
        JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser(getRealDesktop());
        FileFilter jpg = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".jpg", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
        FileFilter jpeg = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".jpeg", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
        FileFilter png = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".png", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
        c.setFileFilter(png);
        c.setFileFilter(jpeg);
        c.setFileFilter(jpg);
        c.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(c.getSelectedFile() != null){
            String ssLoc = c.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()+c.getFileFilter().getDescription();
            System.out.println(ssLoc);
            BufferedImage bufImg = new BufferedImage(ssWindow.getSize().width, ssWindow.getSize().height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
            ssWindow.paint(bufImg.createGraphics());
            File imageFile = new File(ssLoc);  
            try{  
                imageFile.createNewFile();  
                ImageIO.write(bufImg, "JPG", imageFile);  
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the press action button looks like this:

```
this.setVisible(false);
takeScreenshot("ssTake");
this.setVisible(true);
```

How can make this work?

Comment: Your code is creating an image from the inside of the JPanel.  You need to get the screen coordinates from the JPanel and take a picture of what's on the screen.  Since you did not post code that I can copy into my Eclipse and **execute**, all I can do is leave a comment.

Comment: Check out my [JCropFrame article](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=76), which might do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Gilbert Le Blanc.

I reworked a bit the code to use the robot for this and now the code looks like this:

```
private void takeScreenshot(String print){
        JFileChooser c = new JFileChooser(getRealDesktop());
        FileFilter jpeg = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif)", "jpg", "jpeg", "jpe", "jfif");
        c.setFileFilter(jpeg);
        c.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(c.getSelectedFile() != null){
            ssLoc = c.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()+".jpg";
            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
                Robot robot = new Robot();
                BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(ssWindow.getX(),ssWindow.getY(),ssWindow.getWidth(),ssWindow.getHeight()));
                ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(ssLoc));
                System.out.println(print);
            } catch (AWTException | IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```